# AWS Amplify Auth.confirmSignIn cannot log out when entering the wrong verify code using custom flow

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, swiftui, aws-amplify, custom-authentication

Amplify Framework Version: 2.1.0
Dependency manager: Swift PM
Swift version: 5.7
CLI version: 10.4.0
Xcode version: 14.1
I get the verify code and I find out I sign up the wrong email, In this case, I couldn't sign in again  with the correct email or log out the wrong email.

swift code

```
func confirm(response: String) async {
             do {
                 let verifyResponse = try await Amplify.Auth.confirmSignIn(challengeResponse: response)
                 print("Confirm sign in succeeded")
                 print("verifyResponse : \(verifyResponse.nextStep)")
                 switch verifyResponse.nextStep {
                 case .done:
                     print("Signin complete")
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         Task{
                             print("confirm func")
                             self.authState = .test
                         }
                     }
                 case .confirmSignInWithCustomChallenge(_):
                     print("confirmSignInWithCustomChallenge")
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         Task{
                             await self.signOut()
                             self.authState = .login
                         }
                     }
                     print("")
                 case .confirmSignInWithSMSMFACode(_, _):
                    print("")
                 case .confirmSignInWithNewPassword(_):
                     print("")
                 case .resetPassword(_):
                     print("")
                 case .confirmSignUp(_):
                     print("")
                 }
             } catch let error as AuthError {
                 print("Confirm sign in failed \(error)")
                 self.authState = .login
             } catch {
                 print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
             }
         }
```

lambda code (Verify Auth Challenge Response)

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {
  const expectedAnswer = event.request.privateChallengeParameters.secretLoginCode; 
  if (event.request.challengeAnswer === expectedAnswer) {
      event.response.answerCorrect = true;
  }
  else {
      event.response.answerCorrect = false
  }
  return event
};
```